# Why should add a name before the statement in VHDL?

Tags: vhdl

```
ARCHITECTURE synthesis1 OF vending IS
    TYPE statetype IS (Idle, Opt1, Opt2, Error);
SIGNAL currentstate, nextstate : statetype;
BEGIN
    fsm1: PROCESS( buttons, currentstate ) -- Is necessary to give the PROCESS bl a name?
    BEGIN
    -- Process the input
    END PROCESS; 
END synthesis1;
```

Is necessary to give the Process a name? Why should I set the name?

Comment: All statements can be labeled. There are statements that require a  label - block statements, generate statements and component instantiation statements, required to allow binding (associating a design entity and, optionally, an architecture with an instance of a component, a binding can be specified in an explicit or a default binding indication). All unlabeled concurrent statements are implicitly labeled during elaboration. Labels are also used for pathnames in external names. Labeling multiple processes is useful to distinguish between them when line numbers can't be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is not necessary. It is optional. However, sometimes it is *useful* to give a `process` (or other statement) a name, for example, to make your code easier to read.

Comment: If the process is > 1 screen long, repeat the name at `END PROCESS fsm1;` Makes navigation easier.